# soapui - getting test results back from WsdlRunTestCaseTestStep

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am implementing a feature for my tests that would log the request and response content of my failed test steps. At the moment all I see is something like "Assertion failed" etc, but I need to see what I sent in and what was returned. I am trying to read the results with some success, the code I already have is:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.*
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.*

def suiteRunner = (TestSuiteRunner) runner.getRunContext().getTestRunner()
def listResults = suiteRunner.getResults()
for (TestCaseRunner run : listResults){
    def stepResults = run.getResults();
    for(TestStepResult step : stepResults){
        if(!step.getStatus().toString().equals("OK")){
            def local = step.getTestStep()
            def caseName = local.getTestCase().getName();
            def modalItem = local.getModelItem() 
            log.info modalItem
            if (modalItem instanceof JdbcRequestTestStep){
                log.error "TestCase " + caseName + " step " + local.getName() + " failed"
                log.error "JDBC step failed, query was: " + local.getQuery() 
                log.error "Response content:" + local.getResponseContent() 
            }
            if(modalItem instanceof WsdlTestRequestStep){
                log.error "TestCase " + caseName + " step " + local.getName() + " failed"
                log.error "Request: " + modalItem.getTestRequest().getResponse().getRequest().getRequestContent()
                log.error "Response: " + modalItem.getTestRequest().getResponse().getContentAsXml()         
            }       
            if(modalItem instanceof WsdlRunTestCaseTestStep){
                log.error "TestCase " + caseName + " step " + local.getName() + " failed"
                def target = local.getTargetTestCase()              
            }
        }
```

}
}

The problem is with the last IF (WsdlRunTestCaseTestStep). How do I get the steps that were run with results from the run context?

Comment: Have you seen the -f switch for the testrunner.(bat|sh)? It already does this.

Comment: -f switch only shows me PASS/FAIL and reason for failure if failed, i want to be able to log the request and response if something failed.

Comment: For me it creates log files for every failed call, which contain the request and response. Combined with the -a or -A switch gives me the pass calls.

Comment: Just noticed that you are trying to get JDBC (and possibly) other steps to log out too. Those are currently not implemented. I can offer you this: https://github.com/SiKing/soapui/commit/ecf247834279c15ee7636b4f461ad61925808623